# error after run php index.php console migrate

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, migration, config

i want to make a database migration in CodeIgniter but i got this error

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\r_project>php index.php console migrate
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in C:\xampp\htdocs\r_project\application
\config\config.php on line 43

Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in C:\xampp\htdocs\r_project\application\conf
ig\config.php on line 43

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity:    Notice
Message:     Undefined index: HTTP_HOST
Filename:    C:\xampp\htdocs\r_project\application\config\config.php
Line Number: 43

Backtrace:
        File: C:\xampp\htdocs\r_project\application\config\config.php
        Line: 43
        Function: _error_handler

        File: C:\xampp\htdocs\r_project\index.php
        Line: 316
        Function: require_once



ERROR: An Error Was Encountered

        You have not specified a database connection group via $active_group in
your config/database.php file.
```

i have set my config.php with this

```
$isSSL = function(){
    if( !empty( $_SERVER['https'] ) )
        return true;

    if( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https' )
        return true;

    if ( !isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']))
        return false;

    if( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)
        return true;

    return false;
};

$prot = $isSSL() ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$config['base_url'] = $prot . $host . "/";
```

beside that. i must set my database.php file in folder \application\config\development\database.php

what should i do for this. really needs help

Comment: try $isSSL = function() replace with function isSSL(). an call it by $prot = isSSL() ? 'https://' : 'http://';

Comment: I think the error is in database.php. please recheck it once.

Comment: @Gulshan thank you for replaying. but not work. display another error

Comment: @438sunil i need to get the database.php into config/development/database.php

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the error you are getting, give this a try:

```
$host = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

In terms of setting your database config file, we would need to know more before we could answer.